# set htaccess user name and password in browser using php code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two sites, where a page in site A will return a form as output. when user click the submit button in that form it will be posted to site B.

But in Site B i have set a user name and password in .htaccess, so when user clicks submit button it will ask user name and password from user. But i don't want the user has to i/p the user name and password, instead of that i want to set uname and pwd in the browser when the form is loaded from Site A.

Means browser should not ask uname and pwd for the upcoming requests. is it possible to set the uname and password in browser by using PHP code  ????.

This requirement is for in some cases only, so i can not remove the uname and pwd from .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the username and password in the form action's URL:

```
action="http://username:password@www.example2.com/foo.php"
```

Note that some browsers may ask a configuration for sending a username and password like this.

Comment: thanks, but i don't want to expose the user name and password in URL for security issues

Comment: This is just a notation, the password won't be sent as part of the URL, and this won't be visible in the address bar. BTW there is no difference (from a security point of view) between sending something in the URL or sending the same thing by other means (e.g. in HTTP headers).

Comment: but even it's not shown in address bar, user can get it by see the page source and form action parameter. My problem is mostly user will not access my page from browser, it will be a web service. But some cases user will access from browser at the same time he don't know the htaccess user name and password, so i need to set it in browser in some other way.

Comment: you can't set it in browser without disclosing it to the user